# How to test a viewScoped bean with Joinfaces

Tags: jsf, joinfaces

I'm using joinfaces v3 from some time. 
But I'm experiencing problems regarding tests about the viewScoped beans.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-maven-jar-example) I saw that the equivalent spring scope of ViewScoped annotation is configured automatically by Jsf Spring Boot Starter

But when I try to test a @Component with one of the following annotations
@Scope("view") 
@ViewScoped

I always get a nullPointer on the class org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.integration.ViewScope in the following line

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap()
```

because FacesContext.getCurrentInstance is null

Do we have an example on how to test this kind of beans with joinfaces?
Thank you

Comment: So you can test something like this when not using joinfaces?

Comment: Yes. I'm switching from a java maven project to spring boot in order to use some features that comes easily with spring boot. And I've a lot of tests that involve classes with the Scope "view".

Comment: FYI: spring boot is Java too. And SpringBoot and Maven serve two different purposes. Adding SpringBoot as a tag and making more clear what and how you test is the best way forward

Answer (score 0):

On The Joinfaces documentation there's an example on how to test some jsf bean.
Maybe is useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

*JoinFaces Bean Test* library is probably what you are looking for. See discussion [here.](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/issues/242)

Another possibility is using [joinfaces test mock classes.](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/tree/master/joinfaces-test)